# I have been trying to open a PDF data file from an approved court system, which I have used before. This is the error msg on all devices used

Tags: java, http

Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:535)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:433)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
com.microsoft.azure.appservice.filters.AppServiceFilter.doFilter(AppServiceFilter.java:59)
com.microsoft.azure.appservice.EasyAuthFilter.doFilter(EasyAuthFilter.java:42)
Root Cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Comment: Looks like an array index is out of bounds. That's a programming error... contact the software vendor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.